# delete child not work it just delete half of them

Tags: javascript, three.js

In this code I can't remove all children if I delete half of them?? and I got error `child` is not dignified while i define it? each node has children spheres (nods) and edges (lines) this method delete only nods, why? could any one help me please?

```
function onMouseClick( e ) {


    mouseVector.x = 2 * (e.clientX / containerWidth) - 1;
    mouseVector.y = 1 - 2 * ( e.clientY / containerHeight );


    var raycaster = projector.pickingRay( mouseVector.clone(), camera ),
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );


    for( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
        //INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;

        INTERSECTED = intersects[i].object;
        //obj = intersection.object;

        alert(INTERSECTED.id);

        /*1-*/      //this
        //scene.remove(INTERSECTED);

        /*2-*/      //or this
        for ( c = 0, cl = INTERSECTED.children.length; c < cl; c ++ ) {
            var child = INTERSECTED.children[ c ];
            alert(child.id);
            //child.parent.remove(obj);
            INTERSECTED.remove(child);
            //var lin = scene.children[child.id+1];

            //r lin = scene.getObjectById(child.id+1, true );
            // alert(child.id+1);
            // INTERSECTED.remove(scene.children[child.id+1]);
        }    

        //scene.remove(INTERSECTED);
        scene.add(INTERSECTED);

        animate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem lies in the fact that you loop an array of which you are changing the length. This has nothing to do with three.js but is a basic (beginners) error you made in your javascript code.
Maybe you should rewrite your code and use a while loop instead:

```
while( INTERSECTED.children.length > 0 ){

    var child = INTERSECTED.children[ 0 ];
    INTERSECTED.remove(child);

}
```